# This is with respect to the if statement in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
tuna = "fish"
if tuna == "fish":
   print ' this is fish'
```

I am getting an invalid syntax error while executing the code.
Please correct my code.

Answer (score 1):

In python 3, `print` is a function *`print('hello world')`* not a statement as in python 2.x `print 'hello world'`, basically you forgot the brackets:

```
tuna = "fish"
if tuna == "fish":
    print('this is fish')
```

The output would be:

> this is fish

Comment: `s/brackets/parentheses/`